# How to access a glb model outside the loader | Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am using a GLTFLoader in threejs and a glb model init. I want to use that model outside of the loader, I have already read a lot of Topics but none of them help me fix my problem.

Here's the example I am using: [sculpt.js](https://github.com/gkjohnson/three-mesh-bvh/blob/master/example/sculpt.js)

Here's my code:

```js
init();
render();

// reset the sculpt mesh
function reset() {
  // dispose of the mesh if it exists
  if (targetMesh) {
    targetMesh.geometry.dispose();
    targetMesh.material.dispose();
    scene.remove(targetMesh);
  }

  // merge the vertices because they're not already merged
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();

  // Load a glTF resource
  loader.load(
    // resource URL
    "teeth.glb",
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function (glb) {
      scene.add(glb.scene);

      glb.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
      glb.scene; // THREE.Group
      glb.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
      glb.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
      glb.asset; // Object
    },
    // called while loading is progressing
    function (xhr) {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function (error) {
      console.log("An error happened");
    }
  );
  geometry.deleteAttribute("uv");
  geometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices(geometry);
  geometry.attributes.position.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);
  geometry.attributes.normal.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);
  geometry.computeBoundsTree({ setBoundingBox: false });

  // disable frustum culling because the verts will be updated
  targetMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  targetMesh.frustumCulled = false;
  scene.add(targetMesh);

  // initialize bvh helper
  if (!bvhHelper) {
    bvhHelper = new MeshBVHHelper(targetMesh, params.depth);
    if (params.displayHelper) {
      scene.add(bvhHelper);
    }
  }

  bvhHelper.mesh = targetMesh;
  bvhHelper.update();
}
```

I only need help in the reset function just want the loader to export the model outside the loader as geometry.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `GLTFLoader.load()` is an `asynchronous` function.
So all reset operations are done before your `file.glb` is loaded.
One option you have is to do the rest of the operations inside the `GLTFLoader.load()` callback ([`onLoad`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=gltflo#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.load)).

To get only the geometries of a loaded scene you can [`traverse()`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object#api/en/core/Object3D.traverse) the scene, check if each object is a `Mesh` and if so get the `geometry`, as follow:

```
glb.scene.traverse(obj => {
   if (obj.isMesh) {
     console.log(obj.geometry);
   }
});
```